# What is difference between uidvalidity and list index file in dovecot?

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot, e-mailrelay

Dovecot's document notation says that uid-validity file store IMAP UID to filename mapping but it also says list.index file also store same. If it's so what is need of two files.